# Can I safely modify the "attribute byte count" of binary STL triangles?

Tags: 3d, 3d-modelling, 3d-model

Take a binary STL file.

[Research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)#Binary_STL) suggests the 2-byte "Attribute Byte Count" should be kept as null bytes; however, some software packages adapt it for purposes such as
colour. I was hoping to use this field to store a 16-bit integer in individual elements when creating STL files in my software, without corrupting the file.

A user could then view the file in a viewer (e.g. Windows 10 3D Viewer) as they desire... but when imported into my own software I would be able to use this stored integer with my own software logic to extract a bit more information.

Is it true that modifying the attribute byte count from null to a specified value will corrupt the file for off-the-shelf software usage?

### Update April 2021

I decided to use a separate CSV file to store all my 'additional' data, with each row of the CSV file given an ID that corresponds to the position of the 'triangle' in the binary STL. It's not neat and I now need my workflow to validate the integrity of both files... but it works.